# Python dictionary add in value / optimize

Tags: python, loops, optimization, dictionary

I want to find the number of `tags` in a multidimensional array. I do it like this:

`l['users']` is my data (array)

```
tags = {}
for u in l['users']:
    for p in u['photos']:
        for t in p['tags']:
            if tags.get(t):
                tags[t] +=1
            else:
                tags[t] = 1
```

Is there any cleaner or faster way to write that code?

Comment: You could shorten it with comprehension somewhat. But is it necessary? As for speed are you suing this code on big dictionaries to make the effort/time spent on making the code faster justified?

Comment: Bad implementation is going cost you. Multi-dimensional arrays isn't the best way to store this kind of data. A custom class, or dictionary hierarchy would provide a much more logical structure with a much easier interface for querying data within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this fast and pythonic one-liner solution using [collections.Counter()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an
>   unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and
>   their counts are stored as dictionary values.

```
Counter(t for u in l['users'] for p in u['photos'] for t in p['tags'])
```

DEMO:

```
from collections import Counter

l = {'users': [{'photos': [{'tags': [1,2,3,4,5]}, {'tags': [3,4,5]}]},
               {'photos': [{'tags': [1]}, {'tags': [2,3,4,5]}]}]}

tags = Counter(t for u in l['users'] for p in u['photos'] for t in p['tags'])
print tags  # prints Counter({3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2})
```

Comment: That's not quite what that `print` prints. `tags` is a `Counter`, not a `dict`; it won't print as a `dict`.

Comment: You can loose the list comprehension part and just make it a generator for the same result. i.e., `Counter(t for u in l['users'] for p in u['photos'] for t in p['tags'])`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `collections.defaultdict(int)`, which will use `0` as the default value for any key that doesn't already have one:

```
import collections
tags = collections.defaultdict(int)
for u in l['users']:
    for p in u['photos']:
        for t in p['tags']:
            tags[t] +=1
```

Also, `if tags.get(t)` is a bad way to check whether `t` is a key in `tags`, especially since it'd fail in any context where a value could be considered false in a boolean context. Prefer the following:

```
if t in tags:
```

Answer (score 0):

[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) is good for counting things.